# Is there any way to read write excel having all the functionalities of an excel component without the use of unmanaged code and unmanaged memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

In the solution we are working on, we are using **xlsgen** as the excel component for read/write capabilities of excel files.

On of the main issues is that it uses un-managed code and thus reserves un-managed memory, which even though can be freed (`Marshal.FreeHGlobal`), still and issue for us as our use for the component is very extensive and in almost every bit in the system and even in code executed by reflection which is saved at the customers side and is differs from one customer to another, so to make it short, it is an expensive process to track every bit of code using reserving un-managed memory.

Is there a way/ component which offers Read/Write capabilities to excel which does not involve the use of unmanaged memory and guarantees scalability and performance for large files ?

Comment: Any licensing constraints?

Comment: Lets say i don't have any licensing constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need xls capabillity?
If not, EPPlus is a robust and very fast library for reading / writing. It has also very nice options, like linq support or directly creating a file from a datatable. Also, it has a very nice licencse, nothing like GPL...

Link: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Does it use managed memory and managed code ?

Comment: To my knowledge, it is completely written in C# .NET

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't guarantee that they didn't use any unmanaged memory, does it ?

Comment: No it doesn'T but the source code is free - you can look at it for yourself and determien if it uses unmanaged memory.
But honestly: there should be no reason to use unmanaged memory.

Comment: I checked the source code, it looks using like they're managed memory to me. Thanks :)

Comment: I am glad that I could help you

Answer (score 0):

Searching Google for "[native .net excel](http://www.google.com/search?q=native%20.net%20excel)", I get a number of possible options. One that appears to stand out from the rest is "[NikaSoft NativeExcel](http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcelnet/)". Although I have no experience with it, it may be worth a try.